# How to use only the first comma in a string as a delimiter?

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently I'm using `regexp_substr(token, ''[^,]+'', 1, 2)`to select the second part of the string, but obviously if there's a second comma in there, it'll stop the selection at that second comma. For instance, given the input `12345, Hello, World!`, I'd like to select `Hello, World!` from that rather than just `Hello`. Is there a way to only use the first comma as a delimiter and ignore the second?

Comment: do you have to extract everything after the *first comma*?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Everything after the first comma, even if it has another comma in it.

Comment: Combination of substr and instr would work : select substr('hey ,hello , world',instr('hey ,hello , world',',')+1) from dual;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `instr` and `substr`.

```
select substr(token,instr(',',token)+1) as after_first_comma
from tbl
```